# r checkboxes {manipulate} to toggle data series on and off

Tags: r, checkbox, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a graph which has three lines using ggplot. But then I want to be able to toggle the lines on or off so that when I', looking at an overcrowded plot I can just hide some of the data series. I can't seem to figure out how to do this (or even if its possible) with rstudio's manipulate package which includes checkboxes. Can someone please show me how to do this with this package or any other? Thank you

Code:

```
manipulate((ggplot(MeanFrameMelt, aes(x=variable, y=value, 
           color=id))+ geom_point()), 
           id = checkbox(FALSE, "File1"))
```

MeanFrameMelt (data):

```
id  variable    value
1   file1   V1  0.04114207
2   file2   V1  0.31830645
3   file3   V1  0.05797068
4   file1   V2  0.04138554
5   file2   V2  0.31510753
6   file3   V2  0.05830449
7   file1   V3  0.04157882
8   file2   V3  0.31220430
9   file3   V3  0.05865419
10  file1   V4  0.04177334
11  file2   V4  0.31117608
12  file3   V4  0.05900918
```

Comment: My guess is that constructing a `picker` definition and making some of the definition choices a combination of factors might work.  It's not obvious how to create an "OR" or "AND" menu within `picker` .  You may get a more useful response by submitting a feature request to rstudio.org .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a manipulate question, but rather a question of you have 3 Boolean values to use when creating your plot expression. How to do it? The `checkbox` call creates these. The following doesn't exactly answer your specific question, but shows how to make this less confusing -- just add the lines one by one at the expense of being elegant. This could be done with RStudio, but I'm using a version of manipulate that works without RStudio:

```
require(gWidgets2) ## from github
options(guiToolkit="Qt") ## other choices too
source(system.file("examples", "manipulate.R", package="gWidgets2"))

manipulate({
  plot(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
  if(do_lm)
    abline(lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars))
  if(do_loess)
    with(mtcars, lines(lowess(wt, mpg)))
  ## ...
},
           do_lm=checkbox("Add regression line"),
           do_loess = checkbox("Add lowess fit")
           )
```

Comment: I've been looking at the gWidgets2, and it looks like it could work using it. I just need help implementing it if you could please.   cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf. On page 16 they make a dialogue with a graph. I'm not entirely sure atm how to implement this with my ggplot and make the checkboxes turn each data series on and off.

Comment: As mentioned, the GUI part of this is not so hard. The `manipulate` approach is easiest, but there isn't a "select 0,1 or more from many" widget so the checkboxes are used. (In `gWidgets2` there is `gcheckboxgroup` which can render with checkboxes or a table widget.) When using `ggplot2` you might want to conditionally add layers by making a plot object, say `p`, and adding layers with `+` and the appropriate call. You might start looking here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_point.html

Comment: +1 for the general solution. Though I guess You'd better mention the gWidgets stuff later on cause it might be a little distracting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that uses the `tkexamp` function from the TeachingDemos package rather than `manipulate`:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
tklist <- rep( list(list('checkbox',init="T")), 3 )
names(tklist) <- levels( MeanFrameMelt$id )

tkfun <- function(...) {
    w <- c(...)
    w2 <- names(w)[w]
    df <- MeanFrameMelt[ MeanFrameMelt$id %in% w2, ]
    print(ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value,
                  color=id)) + geom_point() )
}

tkexamp( tkfun, tklist )
```

Or it looks a little nicer if the last line is:

```
tkexamp( tkfun, list(id=tklist), plotloc='left' )
```

Someone else with more familiarity with ggplot2 will need to chime in on how to modify this so that the colors stay the same and optionally the y limits stay the same.

**Edit**

Here is a version of the function to keep the colors and the y limits the same even when not displaying some of the values:

```
tkfun <- function(...) {
  w <- c(...)
  w2 <- names(w)[w]
  df <- MeanFrameMelt[ MeanFrameMelt$id %in% w2, ]
  print(ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=id)) + geom_point() +
    scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
    ylim(range(MeanFrameMelt$value))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing I figured out, based on Rstudio's example bar plot:

```
manipulate(
   barplot(as.matrix(longley[,factor]), 
           beside = TRUE, main = factor),
   factor = picker(1,2,2:3))
```

If you select the third option, `2:3` , it will plot both sets of data.  Presumably the same sort of trickery can be used in other plot types.  I'd be interested in seeing what others can come up with.

Update: the following works, albeit a bit clunky:

```
manipulate(matplot(foo[,1],foo[,c(which(c(fp2,fp3)==1))],t='l'), 
           fp2 = checkbox(TRUE,'col2') ,
           fp3 = checkbox(TRUE,'col3'))
```

You'll need an `fp4` line if you want 3 checkboxes per your comment.

Note -- I have a question posted in Rstudio's forum because I got error messages when trying to assign checkbox outputs to a vector, i.e. `fpick[4]=checkbox(TRUE,'col4')`

Comment: Also see comments in the thread http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/842-manipulate-command-help

Comment: I'm fairly new to R so this is a bit confusing but I'll try and understand what is going on.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's possible to set up, say, checkboxes 1 thru 4, combining the returned values into  a vector and plotting `data[,c(which(checkboxvalues==1))]`  or something along those lines.

Comment: sorry i'm really lost. I would like 3 checkboxes for file1, file2 and file3. How would I go about incorporating it into my original ggplot?